# Use a Identity 2.0 Database to Authenticate a ASP.NET Core 1.0 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to a create a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application and I want it to use the Authentication tables that I already have set up.  These tables were originally created by a ASP.NET 4.6 web application that used Microsoft.ASPNet.Identity.EntityFramework 2.2.0

It looks like things have change in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
because the new Core 1.0 application throws this error when trying to log in:

A database operation failed while processing the request.

**SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.
 Invalid column name 'ConcurrencyStamp'.
 Invalid column name 'LockoutEnd'.
 Invalid column name 'NormalizedEmail'.
 Invalid column name 'NormalizedUserName'.**

The project.json is straight out of the box and looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
}
```

},

Also, I have not changed my ApplicationDbContext, but I have seen some posts about making changes to resolve this issue in that class

Comment: You can start with a fresh Identity database if you'd like. Check out this answer for exact steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856286/8644294

Answer (score 26):

This SQL migration script got me over the above hurdle:

```
Alter Table ASPNETROLES
ADD
 ConcurrencyStamp varchar(255) null,               
 NormalizedName varchar(255) null

 Drop Table AspNetUserTokens

 CREATE TABLE [AspNetUserTokens] (
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    [Value]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserTokens]
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [LoginProvider] ASC, [Name] ASC)
)

Alter Table AspNetUsers
 Add
 ConcurrencyStamp varchar(255) null,
 LockoutEnd DateTime null,
 NormalizedEmail varchar(255) null,
 NormalizedUserName varchar(255) null

Drop Table [AspNetRoleClaims]

CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoleClaims] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [RoleId]     NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoleClaims]
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId]
 FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId])
  REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId]
    ON [AspNetRoleClaims]([RoleId] ASC)

Alter Table AspNetUserLogins
   Add  ProviderDisplayName varchar(255) null
```

There's not been a ton of guidance from Microsoft over how to migrate the database but this fixed the above issue for me.

Comment: I am not relying on migrations and using custom Mappers for ef entity to table mapping. I have inserted `NormalizedName` and `ConcurrencyStamp` in `Users` table it didn't resolved the issue. Than I did the same with `UserRoles` table as you suggested but that didn't worked either

Comment: Did you continue using this database with your 'old' app? That's what I need to be able to do. I see your script didn't  update normalized values either. Wouldn't you need to do that or is Core smart enough to update them

Comment: Worked for me :) Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There's a package available to do this. It literally is for this exact purpose. It is part of Microsoft's codebase, and appears to have been updated recently for Core 2.1.

> A compatibility layer for sharing identity databases between Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AspNetCoreCompat/

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/src/AspNetCoreCompat

It handles the 'differences' between the two schemas with methods like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     Normalized email
    /// </summary>
    public string NormalizedEmail {
        get
        {
            return Email.ToUpperInvariant();
        }
        set { }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Concurrency stamp
    /// </summary>
    public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

I cannot find any real documentation, but I've done the following and it seems to be working ok:

- You install the compatibility package in your OLD website (.NET 4.6)
- You must change ALL references to `IdentityRole`, `IdentityUser`, `IdentityDbContext` etc. to be the classes from the compatibility package.

  ```
  using Compat = Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CoreCompat;

  // update to use the compatibility class
  public class ApplicationDbContext : Compat.IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

  // change all instances, such as this
  Compat.IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
  ```
- You have to upgrade your database to the new format (basically adding a few columns and changing some data types). This is the trickiest stage! You're going to want to do this on a staging environment for sure. I'm using Azure so I just cloned the DB.
- On GitHub I found some migrations scripts by [@samnpathdr called `Migration.zip`](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6425). There are several scripts to be run one by one. I'd recommend running each command one at a time to make sure it all runs.
- Currently there's one table in his script that is custom to his implementation (AspNetUserRolePermissions) so delete references to that.
- If you have any other tables referencing the `AspNetUsers` table, you must drop constraints, update the datatypes and add the constraints back. For example I have a `Notes` table which is linked to a `AspNetUser` so I needed to run `ALTER TABLE UserProfileNote ALTER COLUMN AspNetUsersId nvarchar(450) NOT NULL;` (after removing constraints). **Script the constraints first!**
- Be careful if you have any 'auto migrations' enabled for Core because personally I wouldn't trust them after this kind of change. You should reset to a baseline, or not do EF migrations at all.

https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/6425

Comment: I am having a problem with LockoutEnd field.  Identity 2 wants it to be DateTime.  Core wants it to be DateTimeOffset.  I am unable to get them to co-exist. This error only happens when there the field is not null.  Have you found a way around this?

Comment: Honestly to this day I still have one website that has Lockout related errors all the time in the logs and I'm too scared to try and touch it :-/ Sorry

Answer (score 4):

I manually wrote a migration from the old to the new `Identity` and the application works with both old and new users. Here's the migration if you want to save yourselves some manual work:

```cs
public partial class Identity : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "NormalizedName",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(256)",
            maxLength: 256,
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ConcurrencyStamp",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "LockoutEndDateUtc",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            newName: "LockoutEnd");

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ConcurrencyStamp",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "NormalizedEmail",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            type: "nvarchar(256)",
            maxLength: 256,
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "NormalizedUsername",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            type: "nvarchar(256)",
            maxLength: 256,
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ProviderDisplayName",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", nullable: false),
                ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                    column: x => x.RoleId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUserTokens",
            columns: table => new
            {
                UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(128)", nullable: false),
                LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                Value = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                    column: x => x.UserId,
                    principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ConcurrencyStamp",
            table: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "NormalizedName",
            table: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
            name: "LockoutEnd",
            table: "AspNetUsers",
            newName: "LockoutEndDateUtc");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ConcurrencyStamp",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "NormalizedEmail",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "NormalizedUsername",
            table: "AspNetUsers");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ProviderDisplayName",
            table: "AspNetUserLogins");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable("AspNetRoleClaims");

        migrationBuilder.DropTable("AspNetUserTokens");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also keep in mind that is one way migration. To be able still use old solution you could force  .net core to use old password hashing algo

```
services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);
```