# JWT Authentication in ASP.Net Core with ASP Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

A couple of years ago I implemented a web application using .Net 4.6 and ASP Identity and I used JWT for authorization and authentication on the backend and used AngularJS for the client. As I recall, I used a series of posts on BitOfTech.net as a basis for the implementation. I used VS2015 community for the implementation.

I am now trying to re-implement this application in VS2017 Community using ASP Identity Core, .Net Core and Angular 4.

I have parts of the Angular working and have re-implemented the JWT tokens, and while it responds to the .well-known/openid-configuration end point with the correct data and the AuthorizationController is called with the Token Endpoint the login fails.

I have worked through a number of the problems, the biggest of these being upgrading that database using a [SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315812/use-a-identity-2-0-database-to-authenticate-a-asp-net-core-1-0-application) but the AccountController fails when it calls _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync() which returns false. I am using Postman to run the test and the username and password are correct because the old version running against the same aspnet Identity DB works.

In the earlier project I had to implement a SQLPasswordHasher derived from PasswordHasher which overrode VerifyHashedPassword(). I forget the reasons why I needed to do this but I seem to recall that because the DB was initially built using ASP.Net Membership the stored passwords were generated using an older algorithm.

So I decided to re-implement this and found that I needed to create a class based on IPasswordHasher which implemented VerifyHashedPassword() and HashPassword()

Then all I had to do was during startup inject my SQLPasswordHasher into the UserManager by assigning userManager.PasswordHasher = SQLPasswordHasher

But that is where I am stuck. In my old implementation there was a place in my code where I created a UserManager but the startup has changed so much that I can't find where I would do this. Google suggested modifying IdentityConfig.cs but this no longer appears to be used.

If someone could explain to me how I inject my own PasswordHasher into the UserManager as it is created I would be eternally grateful.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I am using OpenIddict.

Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: You can have a look at the post from Scott Brady at https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/ASPNET-Identity-2-Configurable-Password-Hasher. I think it's good for resolving your issue.

Comment: On further reflection, I think I may be confused. Well, I know I am confused, but I think I may know why.
The UserManager does have PasswordHasher implementation, so it occurs to me that I want to inherit from that and override some methods.
The IPasswordHasher interface is intended for people who wish to develop their own specific algorithm and not extend the original.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. So when you are customizing ASP.NET Core Identity, you can create new service that inherit from UserManager<User> and override some methods.

Answer (score 0):

I was correct. I needed to override PasswordHasher and not create a totally new class.

This can be closed