# SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedName'. Invalid column name 'ConcurrencyStamp'. Invalid column name 'NormalizedName'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Why am I getting exception when using PasswordSignInAsync on .NET Core Identity?  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

```
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
SqlException: Invalid column name 'NormalizedName'.
Invalid column name 'ConcurrencyStamp'.
Invalid column name 'NormalizedName'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)
```

I can create user, reset password and so on. '`NormalizedName`' is not even part of  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`. All the columns exist in my table

```
select LockoutEnd, TwoFactorEnabled, PhoneNumberConfirmed, PhoneNumber, ConcurrencyStamp, SecurityStamp, 
PasswordHash, EmailConfirmed, NormalizedEmail, Email, NormalizedUserName, UserName, Id, LockoutEnabled, AccessFailedCount
from [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
```

Comment: Not sure how this is possible but I got it working by making these changes in the Startup.cs

 ` services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
  {
               options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
   }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>(); `

to

 ` services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>();`

Answer (score 6):

The exception is actually coming from the `AspNetRoles` table and not the `AspNetUsers` one. If you've migrated an old Asp.Net `Identity` to Asp.Net Core, then there's two new fields you need to add to the Roles table. Here's a migration for that:

```cs
public partial class Identity : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "NormalizedName",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(256)",
            maxLength: 256,
            nullable: true);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "ConcurrencyStamp",
            table: "AspNetRoles",
            type: "nvarchar(max)",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "ConcurrencyStamp",
            table: "AspNetRoles");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "NormalizedName",
            table: "AspNetRoles");
    }
}
```

If you want the full `Identity` migration including the users, claims and other tables, you can refer to my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65003440/1348324