# Asp.NET Core & EF Core with an existing identity database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have an existing database.  It uses the asp .net identity I built in .NET 4.x.  Everything in it works fine.  I have run a scaffold dbcontext.  I have imported a few of my files into this asp .net core project and ef core.  When I attempt to login to test in my asp .net core project and see if anything works, I get an error shown below.  I do not know where to track this and am not sure where to start.  I think the issue has something to do with trying to scaffold the identity tables.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  TIA

PS. I'm trying to do this in the asp .net core 5 beta

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
Invalid column name 'ProviderDisplayName'.
Invalid column name 'UserId1'.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__169_0(Task`1 result) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__277_0(Object obj)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9.FindByLoginAsync(String loginProvider, String providerKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at ScoringAppAndBackend.Libraries.DataAccess.Login(UserManager`1 userManager, String UserName, String Password) in C:\Users\theev\source\repos\ScoringAppAndBackendCore\ScoringAppAndBackend\Libraries\DataAccess.cs:line 2184
at ScoringAppAndBackend.Controllers.MobileUserApi.MobileUserLoginController.PostAsync(MobileLogin val) in C:\Users\theev\source\repos\ScoringAppAndBackendCore\ScoringAppAndBackend\Controllers\MobileUserApi\MobileUserLoginController.cs:line 32
at lambda_method7(Closure , Object )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:8cc157c5-9ecb-422a-8927-2d4f2170e37f
Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16

Comment: I've now done two additional items.  1.  I have marked the asp net objects as [NotMapped].  this was step 1.  Step 2.  I have found the following url on SO and updated my schema.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315812/use-a-identity-2-0-database-to-authenticate-a-asp-net-core-1-0-application.

Comment: These two steps have resolved the error.  Now, I am getting no user is found.  So, I still don't have something setup right.  I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I spent time on this today.  The issue was that the fields NormalizedUserName & NormalizedEmail must be set in the sql server db.  Once I did that, problems were resolved.